# iOS Crash: -[NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: nil argument

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crash, null

There are multiple arguments in this method, but I do not know which one it is talking about when telling me nil argument. The code below is the one generating the error. This is all according to an error I've seen according to crashlytics.

This is the exception error

```
 OHASMarkupParserBase.m line 62
__56+[OHASMarkupParserBase processMarkupInAttributedString:]_block_invoke
```

This is the line of code that caused the crash.

```
[regEx enumerateMatchesInString:processedString.string options:0 range:range
                          usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop2)
```

Comment: Is there a race condition in your code?  Could this code be running before your attributed string has been initialized?